# Return all objects from collection except for ones with certain field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, object, collections, mongoose

I am developing a node.js application using Mongoose (very new to it all) and I have a collection of products. Each product has a "username" field which links it back to a certain user. I want to get all of the objects in this collection, except for the ones where the username is equal to the username of the logged in user.
 I know I can return all from a particular user using :

```
app.get('/profile', function(req, res){
var msg = req.flash('message');
var username1 = req.user.username;
Products.find({'username': username1}).sort('-date').exec(function(err, docs){
    res.render('profile', { title: 'Products', products: docs, flashmsg: msg});
});
});
```

But how would I go about return objects with the exception of the logged in user?

Comment: Can you try Products.find({'username':{$ne: username1}) ?

Comment: Thanks @SagarReddy worked perfectly!